# Primefaces calendar restricted not work correctly

Tags: primefaces

p: calendar not work correctly if after selecting the date in the restricted range can type in the text box and change to a date outside the range.

```
 <p:calendar value="#{addFacturaMB.facturaUtilNew.fechaEmision}" 
  mindate="#{administrarMB.fechaInicio}" 
  maxdate="#{administrarMB.fechaFin}" 
  id="popupButtonCal1" showOn="button" 
  required="true" locale="es" effect="show" 
  navigator="true"/>
```

Comment: Consider having a validator, the restriction is merely a javascript one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you described the `<p:calendar>` `mindate` and `maxdate` attributes are working correctly.   They will only limit what date can be selected on the calendar pop up.

If you don't want the user to change the date with the text box you have a few options to stop this.

1. Set your calendar input text box to be read only.  `<p:calendar readonlyInput="true" />`
2. Change your calendar mode to be inline  `<p:calendar mode="inline" />` so there is no input text box.